# What does Settings->Privacy Settings->Back up my data do?

Tags: settings, backup

I'm Running 2.3 Gingerbread.
There is a setting
Settings->Privacy Settings->Back up my data

If checked, what data does this back up?
Where is it backed up?
How do I restore it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What info does Google backup?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15434/what-info-does-google-backup)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This setting backs your data up to Google's magic cloud. It includes what apps you have installed, and some apps' settings (if they are written to take advantage of it) which are restored when you first sign in to a new phone.

Relevant quote from the [Android 2.3 user guide](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fgooglephone%2FAndroidUsersGuide-2.3.pdf), pg 18:

> You can choose to back up some of your
>   data, such as your bookmarks, your
>   user dictionary, your Wi-Fi passwords,
>   and many other settings, to your
>   Google Account, on Google servers.
>   Some third-party applications may also
>   take advantage of this feature. That
>   way, when you need to replace your
>   phone (when you upgrade or replace a
>   lost phone), or if you reinstall an
>   application, you can restore your
>   settings and other data. For
>   information about changing this
>   setting later, see “Privacy settings”
>   on page 370.

That setting controls apps' ability to use [this API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html), which includes Google's apps such as Market.