# how to recover the back-up data from google account?

Tags: google-backup

I backed-up my passwords and data from phone on to my google account. Then reset the device. how can i recover the saved passwords?(specifically wifi password)

Answer (score 3):

As soon as you log back in to your Google account, your old apps should start reloading and their data restored. Of course, if you don't have your WiFi password, this is all happening over your cell data link, which could take a while. You might want to enter the password manually to make the process go more quickly & not consume your data usage.

You should probably note that [not all apps, including built-in apps, save all data](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/7941/59189).

Answer (score 1):

I think, This can help you :

> 1. Open your device's Settings menu.
> 2. Under "Personal," touch Backup & restore.
> 3. Check the box next to "Automatic restore".

[Back up or restore data on your device](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2819582?hl=en)

good day.

Comment: I just replaced my Nexus 5X as it got stuck in a boot loop, they sent a replacement. I got the new Nexus 5X, signed in as I always do, but it did not restore.. This is the first time it's NOT restored. It has done it since Nexus S > Nexus 4 > Nexus 5 > Nexus 5X.. Always copied all settings and background images and apps. But now.. It has not.. Any way to FORCE it?

Answer (score 0):

Backed-up data will be restored as soon as you login to your Google account. See -

> `Settings>Backup & Restore>Automatic Restore`

for more details.

Answer (score -1):

As soon as you log back into your Google account, go to: Settings -> Backup & Restore -> Automatic Restore.