# Can I restore apps and settings from Google backup later?

Tags: google-backup

When setting up a new device, Android offers to restore apps and settings from Google Backup.

If I'd like to do it later, is it possible to do? Or is the setup the only time you have access to this functionality?

Android 6.0.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/103345/how-to-recover-the-back-up-data-from-google-account? Not sure

Comment: On my Nexus 5 on Android 6.0, there's *Backup & reset* on Android Settings, but there's no option to restore from there. On the other hand, perhaps [Trigger Setup Wizard at next boot using command-line](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/137324/trigger-setup-wizard-at-next-boot-using-command-line) might be a workaround.

Comment: Afraid that's not possible: restore is either done on device initialization (setup), or not. Neither can you pick *what* to restore. Which is why I always recommend to at least not rely on that backup alone (or use a different solution altogether). As I never used it (for the reasons named plus for privacy – I don't like Google having access to my clear-text WiFi passwords, for example), I cannot give a definite answer, though.

Comment: @Izzy - on initialization, it offered me a choice of which programs to restore

Comment: @DVK Thanks for that detail! Must have been added at some point then. Though that doesn't help the OP either as it doesn't let you chose *when* but just *what*.

Comment: @Izzy - yep. Especially as I'm the OP :)))  I'll consider restoring from backup once I decide what to do rooting-wise (stock root or a custom ROM) this weekend, and hopefully will be able to get an answer experimentally out of that

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I found an app that totally saved my life on this matter!
The app is called [Activity Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.szalkowski.activitylauncher&hl=en) and from this you can open Android Setup app (the one with Restore icon) and click on the activity `CloudRestoreFlowActivity`. The restore screen will show up and you can select a backup file you previously uploaded to Drive.

FYI, I use Mi A2 Lite with Android 9.0 Pie.

Comment: Activity Launcher instalel but "Android Setup app"? I cant see it, would you be that kind and give us a screenshot? Thanks! Would be a life saver.

Comment: Searching for CloudRestoreFlowActivity worked for me. It took some time, but the entry eventually popped up under "Android Setup"

Comment: This didn't work for me on a Sony Xperia 5 II with Android 10. The activity is in the list, but starting it does nothing.

Comment: Great answer! It worked for me, but I faced a challenge and wanted to share what happened. The first time I tried it, it worked great. But then when I tried to launch CloudRestoreFlowActivity a second time, nothing happened. I noticed in logcat there was a crash and it said something about the restore already being in progress. I resarted my phone, no luck. What I finally figured out was I had to clear app data on the Data Restore Tool app. Finally I could launch CloudRestoreFlowActivity again. This was on Android 12.

Comment: well, in my case on Galaxy S10 it ONLY INSTALLED the apps but did not restore any of their data! :( Then I tried installing TWRP and it required data format, so I did it and this time went through the initial phone setup properly and didn't skip the transfer of data from old phone. When I let it do in this first phase it actually worked properly and installed apps along with their data (not all of them are compatible with this functionality)

Answer (score 1):

download it from here.....

https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/android-setup/android-setup-1-0-290634092-release/android-setup-1-0-290634092-android-apk-download/download/

then launch it from android setup from activity launcher