# Is it possible to transfer app data from a backup to another backup/pc?

Tags: backup, data-recovery

[image]

The backup on the bottom has more app data  (85 app data) than the one at the top (33 app data). I was wondering if it is possible to extract/transfer the data onto the backup on the top or onto another storage platform such as a pc or an sd card. I cannot renew the backup at the bottom as the device that backup was made from has been reset and the backup at the top was the retrieved data from the backup at the bottom. If it is not possible, is the data still stored in some other cloud storage app such as google play?

Comment: I personally never used that kind of backup. looks like it is urgent. maybe try to download to PC, or try to increase the expire date straight from PC browser https://drive.google.com/drive/backups if you enabled sync in photos app you might download pictures before they get deleted by unwanted sync https://photos.google.com

Comment: How do i increase the expiry date using the PC browser? I'd only want the app data transfered.
ㅤ
ㅤ
ㅤ
ㅤ
it's you!

Comment: please reply, i've got little time left!

Comment: as I said never used that. searching for drive+backup will give you some hints. https://support.google.com/android/answer/2819582

Comment: should be even possible to restore on emulator (like BlueStacks) https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213374

Comment: Very late reply, but I was wondering what kind of backup system you use?

Comment: TWRP + Migrate-NG