# adb v backup & restore

Tags: adb, backup, google-backup

Two ways to back up apps are adb (for example, `adb -apk -noshared -all`) and backup/restore (settings - backup % reset - Backup my data, also known as google backup).

What's the difference? Is one preferable to the other if you want to backup and restore all apps and settings?

[Full Backup of non-rooted devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/full-backup-of-non-rooted-devices) contains a lot of information on what you can backup with adb, but only links to info on google backup.

[What info does Google backup?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15434/what-info-does-google-backup) is linked, but seems out of date.  Claims I've read for google backup range from it does a good job of backing up settings, apps and related data to it does very little and is not reliable.